# $a, b, c, d$ are positive integers， $a-c|a b+c d$, and then $a-c|a d+b c$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> $a, b, c, d$ are positive integers， $a-c|a b+c d$, and then $a-c|a d+b c$

proof: really easy when use $a b+c d-(a d+b c)$

---

however my first thought is, $a-c| a b+c d+k(a-c)$, and set some $k$ to prove, failed.

*question1* : is this method could be done? any other methods?

*question2* : `And` is there any relations between the question and determinant/matrix

$$\begin{array}{cc} a & d  \\-c & b \end{array}$$

Comment: Suppose $a=4, b=1, c=1, d=2$. Then $a-c=3$ is a divisor of $ab+cd=6$, but not of $ad+bd=10$.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen typo, fixed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT:

$$ab+cd-(ad+bc)=b(a-c)-d(a-c)=(a-c)(b-d)$$

Alternatively, $$ab+cd=b(a-c)+bc-(a-c)d+ad=(a-c)(b-d)+ad+bc$$ we  are reaching at the same point

Comment: Yes, this is one right/efficient/simple method.
How do you think about my question1 and question2.

Comment: this answers question 1: $k=(b-d)$ ;)

Comment: @N.S. oh... good to know that...

Answer (score 1):

As lab gave you the $k$ which works for question 1, here is the answer to question 2:

$$\det \begin{pmatrix} a & d  \\-c& b \end{pmatrix} = \det \begin{pmatrix} a & b  \\-c & d \end{pmatrix}+\det \begin{pmatrix} a & d-b  \\-c & b-d \end{pmatrix}$$
$$ = \det \begin{pmatrix} a & b  \\-c & d \end{pmatrix}+(b-d)\det \begin{pmatrix} a & -1  \\-c & 1\end{pmatrix} = \det \begin{pmatrix} a & b  \\-c & d \end{pmatrix}+(b-d)\det \begin{pmatrix} a+c & 0  \\-c & 1\end{pmatrix}
$$

The solutions is pretty artificial though...